# How to make XAMPP/LAMPP on a Linux Chromebook automatically start or turn on?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromebook, xampp, google-chrome-os

[image]

How to make XAMPP/LAMPP on a Linux Chromebook automatically start or turn on when the Chromebook/device is turned on?

I hope that maybe someone has tried it, maybe there is someone who has experience in Linux and Chromebook.

All suggestions and answers are greatly appreciated.